# How to remove TapStops location recursively using enumerateAttributes in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, nsattributedstring, nstexttab

I've to show HTML data in `UITextView`, this HTML data sometimes contains nested tags for lists, which cause extra padding on device, I want to remove extra padding using swift side since padding from CSS doesn't seem to be working here. Here is how my code and sample data looks like

```
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedQuestionMessage!)
    mutableAttributedString.enumerateAttributes(in: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedString.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, stop) in
        let maybeParagraphStyles = attributes.filter {$0.key == NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle }
        maybeParagraphStyles.forEach({ (style) in
            if let paragraphStyle = style.value as? NSParagraphStyle {
                let mutableParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle

                let modifiedTabStops = mutableParagraphStyle.tabStops.map {
                    NSTextTab(textAlignment: $0.alignment, location: $0.location - mutableParagraphStyle.defaultTabInterval, options: $0.options)
                }
                if modifiedTabStops.count > 0 {
                    mutableParagraphStyle.tabStops = modifiedTabStops
                }
                var mutableAttributes = attributes

                mutableAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle] = mutableParagraphStyle
                mutableAttributedString.removeAttribute(.paragraphStyle, range: range)
                mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: mutableParagraphStyle, range: range)
            }
        })

    }
    textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
```

this works fine, but fails for when I've to display data like this

```
<html> <head> <style type="text/css"> 
 body {  font-size: 14px;  font-family: -apple-system,
 Arial, sans-serif; color: black; margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 20px; } </style> </head> 
<body> <p>To make this more tangible, let’s bring this concept to 
the team level. What would you say are the aspirations for your 
team?</p>
<ul><ul type="disc"><li>What is the overall goal?
<ul><ul style="list-style-type:circle"><li>E.g., Increase customer 
loyalty by 20% as measured by Repeat Customer Rate</li></ul></ul></li>
<li>What specific initiatives do you think would lead you to achieve 
it?<ul><ul style="list-style-type:circle"><li>E.g., Implement a loyalty
program that rewards customers each time they purchase a certain value
 of items</li></ul></ul></li></ul></ul> </body> </html>
```

which show data like this, as you can see there is alignment issue & padding too, any suggestions ?
[image]

Comment: What's your target rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see it's obvious in the code that I'm reducing `NSTextTab` by subtracting it `defaultTabInterval` from it, head indent of `paragraphStyle` is equivalent to in this case `modifiedTabStops.last?.location`, since I was changing the location of both tabs of `NSTextTab`, changing the `headIndent` solve my problem. Here is the solution.

```
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedQuestionMessage!)
    mutableAttributedString.enumerateAttributes(in: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedString.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, stop) in
        let maybeParagraphStyles = attributes.filter {$0.key == NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle }
        maybeParagraphStyles.forEach({ (style) in
            if let paragraphStyle = style.value as? NSParagraphStyle {
                let mutableParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle

                let modifiedTabStops = mutableParagraphStyle.tabStops.map {
                    NSTextTab(textAlignment: $0.alignment, location: $0.location - mutableParagraphStyle.defaultTabInterval, options: $0.options)
                }

                if modifiedTabStops.count > 0 &&  mutableParagraphStyle.headIndent > mutableParagraphStyle.defaultTabInterval {
                    if let location = modifiedTabStops.last?.location {
                        mutableParagraphStyle.headIndent = location
                    }
                    mutableParagraphStyle.tabStops = modifiedTabStops
                }
                var mutableAttributes = attributes
                mutableAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle] = mutableParagraphStyle
                mutableAttributedString.removeAttribute(.paragraphStyle, range: range)
                mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: mutableParagraphStyle, range: range)
            }
        })

    }
```